# Laravel 5 validate date as php Y format e.g 2015?

Tags: php, date, laravel, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

I have a form that uses bootstraps datepicker. I want to collect the year as **2015** for example

**How do i do that?**

The datepicker code is this:

```
$('#manufacture_year').datepicker({
    format: " yyyy",
    viewMode: "years",
    minViewMode: "years",
    endDate: FromendDate,
    autoclose: true,
    disableEntry: true
});
```

I'm displaying the datepicker like so:

```
{!! Form::text('manufacture_year', null, ['placeholder' => '1984', 'class' => 'form-control datepicker-default', 'id' => 'manufacture_year']) !!}
```

My validation rules are:

```
'manufacture_year' => 'required|date|date_format:Y'
```

When i submit the form i keep getting:

> The manufacture year is not a valid date.,The manufacture year does
> not match the format Y.

I put 'Y' as the date format refering to:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Where it states that **'Y' equates a full numeric representation of a year, 4 digits**

Thank you for reading this.

Comment: You should remove the `date` part from the rules array, it's a shortcut for the `YYYY-MM-DD` pattern. As for the second error message, I'd advise you to check that the data you send is correct to see where things go wrong.

Answer (score 0):

With @JoelHinz advice, i've changed my rules array to look like so

```
'manufacture_year' => 'required|date_format:Y'
```

And it works.

Comment: Uhm, I'm glad you got it working, but that's the exact same line as the one you have in your question above... :)

Comment: Careless careless. Thanks again